# SVN: translation between path and node ids?

Tags: svn, path

I have some build info used to identify at runtime the Subversion version # and the URL of the source directory within the repository.

Does SVN use any kind of node ID to identify paths? I'm using an embedded system with a communications link that does not deal well with large data fields, and would be much happier using a 32- or 64-bit node ID, than a long string that does not have a fixed length.

If it does use a node ID, what utility is available to translate between paths and node IDs?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use SHA1 hash like git?

Comment: The only thing is, it works in one direction (path -> ID) but not the other.

Comment: You probably need to keep track of the mapping somewhere.